# Code refactoring in Java, which one is better when there are multiple declarations and operations?

Tags: java, refactoring

I have a question when writing a method with a number of declarations and operations, which one is better so that later on when I refer to it I will have a better grasp, or whether two of these approaches are technically the same.

-- The first approach (write all declarations before doing their operations sequentially):

```java
Map<String, String> transferToStation1 = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, String> transferToStation2 = new HashMap<>();

transferToStation1.put(MetroUtil.LINE, line2Name);
transferToStation1.put(MetroUtil.STATION, station2Name);
transferToStation2.put(MetroUtil.LINE, line1Name);
transferToStation2.put(MetroUtil.STATION, station1Name);

var json1 = new JsonParser().parse(new Gson().toJson(transferToStation1)).getAsJsonObject();
var json2 = new JsonParser().parse(new Gson().toJson(transferToStation2)).getAsJsonObject();

station1.add(MetroUtil.TRANSFER, json1);
station2.add(MetroUtil.TRANSFER, json2);
```

-- The second approach (as soon as declaring a variable, write all of its operations):

```java
Map<String, String> transferToStation1 = new HashMap<>();

transferToStation1.put(MetroUtil.LINE, line2Name);
transferToStation1.put(MetroUtil.STATION, station2Name);

Map<String, String> transferToStation2 = new HashMap<>();

transferToStation2.put(MetroUtil.LINE, line1Name);
transferToStation2.put(MetroUtil.STATION, station1Name);

var json1 = new JsonParser().parse(new Gson().toJson(transferToStation1)).getAsJsonObject();

station1.add(MetroUtil.TRANSFER, json1);

var json2 = new JsonParser().parse(new Gson().toJson(transferToStation2)).getAsJsonObject();

station2.add(MetroUtil.TRANSFER, json2);
```

Comment: It doesn't matter. Whatever you find more readable. But I have to say that your datastructure is very odd. You have to serialize and deserialize a map in order to put it into your main objects. That looks like a kludge, and maybe you should cocentrate your refactoring on that.

Comment: Which is a better data structure that I can work with JsonObject?

Comment: Why do you want to work with `JsonObject`?

Comment: I'd rather write a function so you don't have two identical things going on in the same block.

Comment: Yeah, I also think it's duplicated, then I should make a concrete method for handling these two identical things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general recommendation is to *declare variables as late as possible*, or *as close as possible to their usage*.

In other words, don’t pre-declare variables up-front. Instead, initialise and use them immediately after their declaration.

Thus, the second way is better.

That being said, having essentially the same code duplicated for different variables is also a potential code smell that *might* benefit from refactoring the remove the redundancy. And having variables named `thing1` and `thing2` is almost *never* a good idea, and indicates that you might want to use an array, or a loop, or both.

Comment: Additionally, with the second approach you can easily see what lines of code belong together. So you can extract those lines into methods to remove some of the code duplication.